# Why is such a huge difference between answering a question and flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I started the question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267507/how-to-encourage-flagging-as-duplicate-instead-of-answering-unoriginal-questions) but I was not satisfied with the result.

**BASIC IDEA:**

- ***There is a huge number of new questions each day, part of them unclear, off-topic, duplicate or asked without effort of finding the answer.***

**AS A RESULT**

- ***There is a huge number of duplicate answers, or answers to bad questions just to get reputation***

**Shouldn't some modification be made to encourage flagging and the quality of the site?**

Comment: Line one in our defences: downvotes. They are free on questions for a reason.

Comment: By the time a question is downvoted or a flag is accepted the user might have already received and accepted an answer